# Converting non English words to % separated string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

I have a Persian word like this: `word = می‌باشد`.
If I run this:

```
word.encode(encoding='utf-8')
```

I see this in Python IDLE:

```
b'\xd9\x85\xdb\x8c\xe2\x80\x8c\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb4\xd8\xaf'
```

I want to convert the above line to a string that removes `b'` and replaces all `\x` with `%`. 
So I want to get this string:

```
%d9%85%db%8c%e2%80%8c%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b4%d8%af
```

What is the best way to do  this in Python 3?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`urllib.parse.quote`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote):

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> word = 'می‌باشد'
>>> urllib.parse.quote(word, encoding='utf-8')
'%D9%85%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%AF'
```

You can omit `encoding='utf-8'` because `utf-8` encoding is used by default.

Comment: wooow that is an excellent answer it worked, thank you so much.